# How to bring the clock back to the center in gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome, 11.10, gnome-shell, clock

I am using Gnome-shell on Ubuntu 11.10.

For some reason, after I added the usual extensions (Weather Indicator, System Monitor etc) the clock moved to the right - I did not install an extension for it to do so; it just did.

How can I get the clock back to the center?

Answer (score 8):

(converted OP answer originally in his/her question)

The solution I found to this is as follows.

1. Click the system monitor,
2. go to preferences and
3. untick 'move the clock'.

Answer (score 1):

Another extension that causes this behaviour is "Extend Left Box" -- I had so many extensions that I didn't notice it, and then I installed "Status Area Horizontal Spacing" and had to poke around a bit.