# Move clock to center in Gnome Shell 3.24

Tags: clock, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-shell

I'm on Ubunut 17.04 with Gnome shell 3.24.2.
Ever since the fresh install, the clock got placed to the right side of the top panel. 
I have not found a way to move it to the center. 
I'm aware of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103050/how-to-bring-the-clock-back-to-the-center-in-gnome-shell) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453969/how-can-i-order-gnome3-shell-extensions-at-the-top/661015#661015) post, but they both didn't help. For one - I don't have system-monitor extension installed and I can't find the extension in `/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` or `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` that causes this behavior in the first place.

Is the clock at the right side default in 17.04 or is this just my system? Seems a terrible choice.

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered the same problem, and found a fix.

In `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes` there's a `classic.json` file that holds the configuration for the current shell -

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "gnome-classic.css",
    "enabledExtensions": [LIST_OF_STUFF],
    "panel": { "left": ["activities", "appMenu"],
               "center": [],
               "right": ["a11y", "keyboard", "dateMenu", "aggregateMenu"]
             }
}
```

All you need to do is to move the "dateMenu" item to the center.
I also had the *Window List* extension enabled after every boot, and removing it here solved the problem.